# Is it possible to implement a chat-head everywhere on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, chat, head

do you see what Facebook chat-heads are? It's those floating buttons you can move on the screen and interact with. On Android the chat-heads can leave Facebook and be everywhere on the screen. But what about iOS? Is it possible to implement a control of this kind you can use everywhere in the system? (I really doubt it, but I have to be sure).

I need to port an Android app and the chat-head-like control is an important feature of the Android version.

Thank you for your time.